# Raspberry pi 4 gpio pins not working

Tags: gpio, pi-4, rpi.gpio, python-3

My Raspberry pi 4 gpio pins are not working for some reason I tried uninstalling and reinstalling rpi.gpio and gpio and it did not work here is the code

```
import RPI.GPIO as GPIO
import time

led = 26
RST = 5
color = str(input())

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(led, GPIO.OUT)

while True:
    color = input("Type Color: ")
num =  1
if color in ['Red' 'red']:
    num = 1
    Change_Color( num )
    print ('Red')
    
def Change_Color( int ):
    GPIO.output(led, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(.1)
    GPIO.output(led, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(1)
    for x in range(int):
        GPIO.output(led, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(.1)
        GPIO.output(led, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(.1)
```

I also tried just using `GPIO.output(led, GPIO.HIGH)` but that did not work. this was intended to be in python3 incase I messed that up.

Comment: How do you KNOW the GPIO didn't work? Incidentally that code won't "WORK" because it is incorrectly indented.

Comment: Have you tried a longer sleep time? Also, if you use the Python string method upper() you won't need to look for both capitalized and non capitalized input - this will be less error-prone. Please post a picture of your wiring.

Comment: Milliways, I do know they do not work it is not the code because I have tried other scripts

Comment: Steve Robillard I have tried a longer sleep time it still did not turn on. the wiring is just a led connected to 26 and ground i am using this for the wiring https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00OG4X0DK/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&linkCode=ll1&tag=pimylifeup-20&linkId=cb7fa3607511531341759cbf4bf004e0

Comment: That code will keep prompting for input but do NOTHING with it.

Comment: You say GPIO doesn't work, and your response to how you know is "I do know" .... but HOW do you know that the GPIO don't work? the breakout header doesn't have an LED on it, so, as far as you've shown, you've got no way of determining if the GPIO works or not

Comment: Post a photo of your Pi connected to ribbon cable, T cobbler, presumably a breadboard, LED and resistor.

Comment: @Bravo I ran gpiotest and it said that the pins i was using failed so I do that they are not working

Comment: @milliways could you show me where the error is so i can fix it

Comment: @user139246 - yes, now you know, because you ran a test 14 hours AFTER I asked HOW you know - you probably wired something wrong and killed some gpio by the look of it

Answer (score 4):

If you think you have damaged one or more GPIO you can carry out a diagnostic test.

The test is a bash (command line) script called gpiotest.
Download [gpiotest](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/code/gpiotest.zip).

The test requires the services of the [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) library (pigpio may be preinstalled).

For the duration of the test nothing must be connected to the GPIO (no LEDs, wires, ribbon cables etc.).

The test checks that each GPIO may be read and written and that the internal resistor pull-ups and pull-downs are functional.

A [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCJFLKWaxHo&feature=youtu.be) showing what happens to the GPIO during a test.

A test with all GPIO okay.

```
This program checks the Pi's (user) gpios.

The program reads and writes all the gpios.  Make sure NOTHING
is connected to the gpios during this test.

The program uses the pigpio daemon which must be running.

To start the daemon use the command sudo pigpiod.

Press the ENTER key to continue or ctrl-C to abort...

Testing...
Skipped non-user gpios: 0 1 28 29 30 31 
Tested user gpios: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
Failed user gpios: None
```

A test showing failed GPIO.

```
This program checks the Pi's (user) gpios.

The program reads and writes all the gpios. Make sure NOTHING
is connected to the gpios during this test.

The program uses the pigpio daemon which must be running.

To start the daemon use the command sudo pigpiod.

Press the ENTER key to continue or ctrl-C to abort...

Testing...
Write 1 to gpio 17 failed.
Pull up on gpio 17 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 18 failed.
Pull up on gpio 18 failed.
Write 0 to gpio 23 failed.
Pull down on gpio 23 failed.
Write 0 to gpio 24 failed.
Pull down on gpio 24 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 27 failed.
Pull up on gpio 27 failed.
Skipped non-user gpios: 0 1 28 29 30 31
Tested user gpios: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
Failed user gpios: 17 18 23 24 27
```

Comment: I ran it and it said that 4 9 12 17 19 23 26 failed

Comment: do you know where i should go from here to fix it

Comment: If you had nothing connected to the GPIO then they are bust and unfixable,

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to suggest how to "fix" poorly designed code, particularly when the end result is unclear.

You obviously haven't tried to run it yourself, because the library is incorrectly named, and even if you fixed this you would see that it NEVER prints anything.

Since you asked, correcting the first 2 errors (and commenting out unused statements) the following at least runs.
It still does NOTHING as num never changes, but it should get you started.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

led = 26
# RST = 5
# color = str(input())

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(led, GPIO.OUT)

while True:
    color = input("Type Color: ")
    num =  1
    if color in ['Red' 'red']:
        num = 1
#         Change_Color( num )
        print ('Red')
```

I suggest you try some simple examples e.g. https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#button-controlled-led

```
from gpiozero import LED, Button
from signal import pause

led = LED(17)
button = Button(2)

button.when_pressed = led.on
button.when_released = led.off

pause()
```

I also suggest you try some of the simple gpiozero code to test your GPIO rather than making assertions that the hardware doesn't work.